# multiple invocations of synchronised methods from a thread

Tags: java, multithreading

If a thread has two invocations to an object's synchronized methods. The thread will gain the monitor lock when executing the first invocation. But then, will the thread:

- release the lock after finishing with first invocation, and try to gain it again when executing the second invocation?
- or, will the thread keep the lock till it finishes with the second invocation also (not only for the first invocation). And then release it at the end?

In other words, will the thread gain the lock, finishes all invocations to the synchronized methods, and then release the lock? ... or should the thread make multiple gains and releases of the lock?

Comment: When the method returns, the lock will be released. When you call another synchronised method afterwards, it will need to get a lock again - just as if it was the first call.

Comment: What type of the lock?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Read here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/locksync.html)

> When a thread invokes a synchronized method, it automatically acquires the intrinsic lock for that method's object and releases it when the method returns.

It's that simple. As the first method returns, the thread will release the object lock and it will have to acquire it again for the second method.

Comment: If you need to run both methods synchronized together, do this `synchronized(obj) { obj.methodOne(); obj.methodTwo() }`, assuming both methods are syncronized. _Nested_ synchronization calls just reuse the existing lock.

Answer (score 1):

when a thread tries to execute a synchronized method A in an object, first it has to acquire a lock on the object.  If acquiring the lock was successful, then the thread can execute method A. No other thread can execute other synchronized method on this object.

If during the execution of method A,  this same thread tries to execute synchronized method B in the same object, it can do so because it already holds the lock on that object.  In this way, the thread can execute both methods A and B and doing so only acquire the lock once.  But as soon as the thread ends the execution of synchronized method A, the lock on that object also gets released.